# Craig's Interpolation Theorem

Tags: logic, model-theory, proof-theory

I'm considering Craig's interpolation theorem in the context of a family of  semantically defined logics. I'm somewhat troubled with the duality used in the formulation. As for all logics considered in the literature I've read, there exists a completeness theorem I've seen both a semantic and a syntactic formulation of the theorem.

Now, some members of the family I'm considering can't have an adequate proof calculus(which was proven before). Obviously, I can still work on Craig's theorem in the axiomatizable logics but what about those having a proper semantic definition but no proof calculus. It it worth considering those, is it possible to proof interpolation merely semantically for these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement of the interpolation theorem certainly also makes sense for logics which are defined only via the semantics. Whether it is possible to prove the theorem for a particular such logic of course depends on the logic itself. There are some semantic methods for proving interpolation properties, though, mainly via algebraic semantics if I remember correctly. It might be interesting to have a look at Maksimova's work on interpolation via the amalgamation property in algebraic characterisations of modal and intermediate logics. Apart from a number of papers on this which are out there, the books
[Interpolation and Definability](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/interpolation-and-definability-9780198511748?cc=at&lang=en&#) by Gabbay and Maksimova, or [Larisa Maksimova on Implication, Interpolation, and Definability](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319699165) seem like a good place to start.

**Edit:** The original proof of the Lyndon interpolation theorem, a refinement of Craig interpolation, also seems to have been semantic, i.e., model-theoretic. The reference is [this](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103039458)

Comment: So for these logics, it would be possible to have semantic interpolation but no syntactic equivalent?

Comment: Yes, in principle it should be possible to have Craig interpolation in a purely semantic way. Also, the original proof of the Lyndon interpolation theorem seems to have been model-theoretic, by the way. I've updated my answer to include this.